# How to write system calls on debian/ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, debian, recovery

I am trying to write a system call of my own. It would just return the current time. I know the concept of what should I do and I did go through a couple of links like these:

- [Implementing a System Call on Linux 2.6 for i386](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/)
- [Another of the System call implementation](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/users/faculty/sandhya/csc256/assignments/adding-a-system-call.html)

But I am still confused and have not got the desired result. The kernel is not compiling and its crashing due to problems. I have tried it on debian latest stable release of 3.X.X

Could someone point me out to a clean `hello world` kind of program to develop system calls?

**EDIT**

To the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12474768/728863), here are my problems:

1. `File 3: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S` is not found in my linux folder. I had to improvise and so modified the following file: `linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`
2. The above (1) new file mentioned had different pattern of `<number> <64/x32/common> <name> <entry point>` and my entry was `313 common
3. The kernel image did compile successfully, but I couldnt call the function. It gives an `undefined reference" error` when i compile it with gcc. Why?

Comment: Please don't put multiple questions in one post. Your second question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow anyhow; I suggest you ask over at http://superuser.com/

Comment: My recommendation is to start small, just with a simple module that does nothing. Then add one small piece at a time, until either it works or it crashes. If it crashes then you know what causes the crash, and can put the relevant code in a question to ask what might have caused the crash. Also, experimenting with kernels is best done in a virtual machine, so you don't have to worry about reboots, and can keep on working even when the kernel crashes.

Comment: Are you familiar with kernel programming? Are you writing the system call as part of a kernel or a kernel module?

Comment: @askmish I am in the processes of learning them. I am writing system call as a part of a kernel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just example how to write a simple kernel system call.
Consider the following C function system_strcpy() that simply copies one string into another: similar to what strcpy() does.

```
#include<stdio.h>

long system_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
   int i=0;
   while(src[i]!=0)
      dest[i]=src[i++];

   dest[i]=0;
   return i;
}
```

Before writing, get a kernel source tar and untar it to get a linux-x.x.x directory.

**File 1: linux-x.x.x/test/system_strcpy.c**
Create a directory within the linux-x.x.x, named `test` and save this code as file `system_strcpy.c` in it.

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
asmlinkage long system_strcpy(char*dest, const char* src)
{
   int i=0;
   while(src[i]!=0)
      dest[i]=src[i++];

   dest[i]=0;
   return i;
}
```

**File 2: linux-x.x.x/test/Makefile**
Create a `Makefile` within the same `test` directory you created above and put this line in it:

`obj-y := system_strcpy.o`

**File 3: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S**
Now, you have to add your system call to the system call table.
Append to the file the following line:

`.long system_strcpy`

*NOTE: For Kernel 3.3 and higher versions.*

*Refer:linux-3.3.xx/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl*

And in there, now add at the end of the following series of lines:

310     64      process_vm_readv        sys_process_vm_readv

311     64      process_vm_writev       sys_process_vm_writev

312     64      kcmp                    sys_kcmp

313     64      system_strcpy           system_strcpy

The format for the 3.3 version is in:
`number` `abi` `name` `entry point`

**File 4: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h**

*NOTE: This section is redundant for 3.3 and higher kernel versions*

In this file, the names of all the system calls will be associated with a unique number. After the last system call-number pair, add a line

`#define __NR_system_strcpy  338`

(if 337 was the number associated with the last system call in the system call-number pair).

Then replace `NR_syscalls` value, stating total number of system calls with (the existing number incremented by 1) i.e. in this case the `NR_syscalls` should've been 338 and the new value is 339.

`#define NR_syscalls 339`

**File 5: linux-x.x.x/include/linux/syscalls.h**

Append to the file the prototype of our function.

`asmlinkage  long system_strcpy(char *dest,char *src);`

just before the `#endif` line in the file.

**File 6: Makefile at the root of source directory.**

Open `Makefile` and find the line where `core-y` is defined and add the directory `test` to the end of that line.

`core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ test/`

Now compile the kernel. Issue:
`make bzImage -j4`

Install the kernel by executing the following command as root(or with root permissions):
`make install`

Reboot the system.

To use the recently created system call use:

`syscall(338,dest,src);` (or `syscall(313,dest,src);` for kernel 3.3+) instead of the regular `strcpy` library function.

```
#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/syscall.h"
int main()
{
 char *dest=NULL,*src="Hello";
 dest=(char*)malloc(strlen(src)+1);
 syscall(338,dest,src);//syscall(313,dest,src); for kernel 3.3+
 printf("%s \n %s\n",src,dest);
 return 0;
}
```

Instead of numbers like 313,etc in `syscall`, you can also directly use `__NR_system_strcpy`

This is a generic example. You will need to do a little experimentation to see what works for your specific kernel version.

Comment: excellent answer! I am trying it out right now.. in the meantime could you please explain File 3 and File 4 in more detail (as to why the same syntax/symantics)

Comment: @footy: I think you are using the 3.3.xx version of kernel on 64-bit machines. In that case I have to edit the answer a little bit. Things have changed from 2.6 to 3.3.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer does not work for kernel 3.5.0 and 3.7.6, producing undefined reference compiling error. To fix the problem linux/syscalls.h should be included in system_strcpy.c instead of linux/linkage.h. Also, it's better to use SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy, dest, src) to define a system call.