# Where to define/declare struct in kernel to be also available outside?

Tags: c, include, linux-kernel

I am creating a new system call in the linux kernel.  It will be taking a reference to a new struct I am creating, thus both the kernel/*.c file and the user program will need to #include a file to get access to the struct type.

Where can I declare my struct?  I have tried putting the declaration into `include/linux/syscalls.h`, but I don't see how to #include this from outside the kernel (and I get an error if I try and compile a program to use it).

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469836/how-to-write-system-calls-on-debian-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/
This is for the 2.6 kernel, but 3.0 didn't change much (if any) in this regard.

Note that it suggests separate headers for kernel and non-kernel usage.

A simple Google search for "linux add syscall" finds this information easily.

Comment: How do I have separate headers, if I need the structure both in AND out of the kernel?  I can see I can use `#include "blah.h"` for a relative import, but how would I import this file **outside** the kernel?