# How do non c languages interact with operating system?

Tags: operating-system, programming-languages, system-calls

On linux (for example), we can directly make system calls using the api provided by OS (open/close/read/write) or we can use functions provided by libc (fopen etc) in C.

How is it achieved in other languages?

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Application Programming Interface (API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface#Language_bindings_and_interface_generators) and [Wikipedia: application binary interface (ABI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [Wikipedia: Language binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) for description of key terms

Answer (score 11):

Your initial premises are wrong: on Linux, when you call, say, [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) in your C code, you're *not* making the syscall but rather calling the function provided by [`glibc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or whatever implementation of the C standard library your program happens to be using—there are others, such as [μLibc](http://www.uclibc.org/), [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) etc), and the implementation of that function actually makes the syscall—properly doing the necessary setup to conform to the target architecture's [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions.

You can make a syscall *directly* in C but it will look much different from just calling `open()`; some pointers are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219644/720999) and [this](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-3.html#ss3.2).

To recap: [the POSIX standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (that one specifying how `open(2)` and friends should looks like and behave) does only specify a rather high-level interface (in terms of the C programming language) but concrete kernels implementing this standard have their own sets of system calls and conventions on how to call them (which differ between H/W architectures for the same kernel), and it's the C standard library which "knows" how to call out to a concrete kernel which makes sure C programs calling POSIX API end up using appropriate system calls with proper set up.  In other words, in a typical C application running on Linux you're not dealing with syscalls directly—you just have an impression you do.

Other languages/runtimes basically have two alternatives:

- Depend on the target platform's `libc` and rely on it to mediate between them and the kernel.
- Directly implement calling the necessary syscalls of the target kernel.

Most of languages/runtimes I'm aware of take the first route (Python, Java to name a few) while some of them take the other route—for instance, the reference implementation of [Go](http://golang.org), [Free Pascal](http://freepascal.org).

**Update 2014-10-13** answering the question from `@tan`'s comment:

> So, if the first route (libc) is taken, how are libc functions invoked from python/java?

Basically, the approach is similar to that of the syscalls: calling into C is, again, sort-of standardized for each combination of hardware architecture and the C compiler. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989/720999) for more info and further pointers.

Note that in reality, most software which is able to interface with C code uses one of these two approaches:

- It is itself written in C, and hence implementing calling out to dynamically or statically linked in external C code is handled by the compiler which compiled the calling software.

  That is, the only thing your software must be concerned of is properly *arranging for* its data to be manipulated by the C side.  One example is making sure a block of memory passed to the C side won't get garbage-collected until the C side is done with it.

  The [`cgo` subsystem](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) of the Go programming language is one example of this approach.
- The calling software uses a library (typically written in C to leverage what the C compiler can do for it) which is able to load C dynamic libraries and properly call out to their functions performing all the required data setup.  See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) for more info.

  Python's [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module implements exactly this approach.

It's harder for me to classify Java's `JNI` and .NET's `P/Invoke` into these two categories. May be they sit somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Yes. I believe the the implementation of the APIs like open/close would set things up (parameters to be shared, return stack pointer etc) and have some assembly code to send s/w interrupt (e.g. trap) to cpu. In case of a C program, these libraries will be loaded and called at run time just like any .so. So, if the first route (libc) is taken, how are libc functions invoked from python/java?)

Comment: @tan, updated my answer to address the question in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

In other languages this is usually (always?) achieved with a wrapper around the native function calls. In reality, it looks something like this.
LanguageX -> Wrapper -> Native Code(C/C++)

Sometimes this wrapper takes the form of an entire framework, such as in [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) for java.
 which also works great for Groovy scripts.

With some languages you can load native DLLs directly into your application in a way similar to C/C++. This is true in the the case of Python using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Other times, native calls aren't needed at all and the same result can be produced directly using your language of choice. Cross-platform GUI toolkits are one small example where native OS calls can be replaced completely. Such as with GTK or QT

Hope that clears things up a bit :) Let me know if you'd like any other language-specific details.

Comment: I don't think Python is closer to C than Java is in any useful sense.

Comment: Thanks, I only meant that it was closer to C in the sense that you can load native dlls directly. Edited for clarification.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Although, it would be interesting to know how exactly does wrapper works.

Comment: That would be rather in-depth and slightly outside the scope of the question. See [Wrapper library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library). In this case the wrapper library would be some form of native interface. kostix answer describes how this all works internally, while my answer is more of a general overview from a user perspective.