# Is `signal()` a system call function on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

From manpage of `signal()` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html

> NAME         top
>
> ```
>    signal - ANSI C signal handling
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>    #include <signal.h>
>
>    typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
>
>    sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
> ```
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> ```
>    * The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
>
>    * By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function
>      does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls
>      sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This default
>      behavior is provided as long as a suitable feature test macro is
>      defined: _BSD_SOURCE on glibc 2.19 and earlier or _DEFAULT_SOURCE
>      in glibc 2.19 and later.  (By default, these macros are defined;
>      see feature_test_macros(7) for details.)  If such a feature test
>      macro is not defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.
> ```

The quote seems to me that `signal()` is not a system call but a wrapper function implemented based on system call `sigaction()`, except "The kernel's signal() system call".

So is `signal()` a system call function or not on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

The manpage for syscalls indicates the wrapper indirection is common, and has a list of Linux syscalls that includes `signal(2)`:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a `signal` system call on Linux (see list of Linux system calls given by Jim). You never trap to a system call directly, you always call a wrapping function (at least you rarely generate the trap directly). As stated in the manual, `signal()` is just a wrapper to a system call that may not be the `signal` one (example is given for `truncate` in the document cited by @Jim). The `signal()` function is in the libc and that library is free to implement that function the way it want provided that the semantic is preserved. So as you mentioned a call to `signal()` may under given circumstances trap to `signal` system call or `sigaction` system call or whatever suitable.

Comment: Thanks. How do you explicitly specify that you want to use a system call or a wrapper function in your program?

Comment: Becareful, calling a system call is not a standard function call... Read @Tim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219501/accessing-a-system-call-directly-from-user-program

Comment: So is `signal()` appearing in a user program always a wrapper function instead of a system call function?

Comment: All so-called system calls in C are **always** wrapper functions. The distinction is rarely useful, and is therefore rarely made. This is like [The Treachery of Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images), where an image of a tobacco pipe is labelled "this is not a pipe" because it's technically a painting and not a smoking implement.