# Implementing a syscall on real-time Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

For educational purposes, I want to implement a system call in Debian Wheezy. I wish to implement it on the kernel that comes in the linux-image-3.2.0--rt-amd64 package. Here is an overview of what I have tried:

To get the kernel source:

```
apt-get source linux-image-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64
```

From that, I get the following files/directories the directory I executed in:

```
linux_3.2.41.orig.tar.xz
linux_3.2.41-2+deb7u2.dsc
linux_3.2.41-2+deb7u2.debian.tar.xz
```

as well as:

```
linux_3.2.41
```

which contains the source code for the kernel.

Then, to make the necessary changes in order to add the system call, I basically followed this page:
[How to write system calls on debian/ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469836/how-to-write-system-calls-on-debian-ubuntu)

The following is a condensed version of the instructions given there modified to reflect the changes I made.

+File 1: linux-x.x.x/vpart_syscalls/vpart_syscalls.c

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long insert_partition(char*dest, const char* src)
{
    printk("<--- the syscall has been called!");
    return 0;
}
```

- File 2: linux-x.x.x/vpart_syscalls/Makefile. Create a Makefile within the same test directory you created above and put this line in it:

  `obj-y := vpart_syscalls.o`
- File 3: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S. Now, you have to add your system call to the system call table. Append to the file the following line:

  `.long insert_partition`
- File 4: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h

In this file, the names of all the system calls will be associated with a unique number. After the last system call-number pair, add a line

```
#define __NR_insert_partition 349
```

Then replace NR_syscalls value, stating total number of system calls with (the existing number incremented by 1) i.e. in this case the NR_syscalls should've been 338 and the new value is 339.

```
#define NR_syscalls 350
```

- File 5: linux-x.x.x/include/linux/syscalls.h

Append to the file the prototype of our function.

```
asmlinkage long insert_partition(int lenTicks, int vpid);
```

just before the #endif line in the file.

- File 6: Makefile at the root of source directory.

Open Makefile and find the line where core-y is defined and add the directory test to the end of that line.

```
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ test/ vpart_syscalls/
```

I then proceeded to build the kernel in a different fashion than is described there:

```
make localmodconfig
make menuconfig (making no changes)


make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=+tm kernel_image kernel_headers
cd ..
dpkg -i linux-image-3.8.*
dpkg -i linux-headers-3.8.*
```

The kernel that is installed boots fine. I made the following c program to test the syscall:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(){
    printk("Calling the new syscall!\n");
    int ret = 100;
    ret = syscall(349, 1, 2);
    printf("call return value: %i\n", ret);
    return 0;

}
```

When I compile and run this program, I get a return value of -1. I check the messages using dmesg and there is no evidence of my printk being called..

If anyone knows where my problem is I would be really really happy! I should say I am not too experienced at changing and building the kernel, but I have learned a lot about it. I read Robert Loves book - linux kernel development and several guides on the webs.

Comment: Please, post results of `uname -a`. Also, you can check your test with `file -k ./test_name` (to check 32/64 bit mode of the program) and `strace ./test_name` to see if the syscall called and what were arguments and the return value (strace should report `syscall_349` for you syscall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the steps 3 and 4 may be incorrect for 64-bit kernels:

```
File 3: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S. 
File 4: linux-x.x.x/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h
```

There are two files here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.41/arch/x86/kernel/

```
syscall_64.c    668 2008-12-24 14:26:58 -0800   
syscall_table_32.S  8659    2012-01-04 14:55:50 -0800
```

First one defines syscall table contents for 64-bit mode  using C file and macro-cheating with [unistd_64.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.41/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h)

```
#define __SYSCALL(nr, sym) [nr] = sym,

const sys_call_ptr_t sys_call_table[__NR_syscall_max+1] = {
....
#include <asm/unistd_64.h>
};
```

Where `asm/unistd_64.h` is

```
 #define __NR_read                               0
 __SYSCALL(__NR_read, sys_read)
```

and so on.

And second one, which you changed - is for 32-bit mode and written using asm file and labels (`.long sys_call_name`).

So, you defined syscall for 32-bit mode and you are using [linux-image-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64) which is basically for " 64-bit PCs".

I think you compiled your test program as `gcc test.c`, which defaults to 64-bit mode. You can try `-m32` option of gcc: `gcc -m32 test.c` to get 32-bit application (this will only work if you have correct cross environment for 32-bit builds) or compile this test on some 32-bit linux.

Or the other choice is to make step "4a": edit `arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h` to add two lines:

```
 #define __NR_insert_partition                               YOUR_NUMBER
 __SYSCALL(__NR_insert_partition, insert_partition)
```

I'm not sure where and how  NR_syscalls for 64bit is defined. It may be generated during build.

Comment: This appears to be the answer. I saw those files (syscall_64.c,   
syscall_table_32.S) when I was attempting to implement the syscall the old way and didn't know what to do with them. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: user1756658, please, comment here after you will test this.